# iPad LTE edition and SIM from smartphone

Tags: ipad, sim, 4g

I am thinking if it is possible to use my phone's SIM card in iPad's SIM slot?
This because I need the 4G just only very few times, so when it will be necessary to use it, I will move the SIM from my smart-phone to the iPad.
It is possible this scenario?

Comment: If you buy an LTE iPad with a T-Mobile sim it includes 200MB/month of data, no charge. I'm not sure if it will work to buy a T-Mobile sim for your iPad to get the free data, but it is at least worth some research. You could also buy it and if it doesn't work return the sim card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, this should work fine. I don't know if I have to answer any longer, but you have to check whether your device has a simlock by a provider. Else you should be free to do this.

You could also use personal hotspot.

Comment: Depends on the form factor of the SIM!